# Textarea visual element?

Tags: nlp, taipy

Before all, congrats for the hard work ! Taipy is a wonderful toolbox to play around with and will be a great time-saver for us to build webapps with python

We are currently building a small demonstrator for a NLP POC. We would like the user to be able to input some lines of text, like what can be done in HTML with .

Is it possible to customize the taipy input control to have multiple lines ? (via properties ?). If not, is a textarea-like input planned in a future release ? I strongly advocate for it as it would be very useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property exists in the *input* properties. It is called *multiline*; you can also change the number of lines through *lines_shown*.

```
<|{text_variable}|input|multiline|>
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/input/#get-user-input). I also recommend browsing through our [Release Notes](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/relnotes/) to see all the changes that was done to Taipy.